# Can I use custom Document Information Panel with SharePoint services (not MOSS)

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, infopath

I know it is possible by using MOSS + InfoPath to create and use [custom Document Information Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms568568.aspx).

However is it possible to write custom InfoPath XML schema and then add it to Content Type definition [programmatically](http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/08/copy-content-types.html) or [declaratively](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms581199.aspx)... Is that possible? Maybe somebody tried something like that?

Comment: Haven't tried it myself, but I would think it should work. After all it's the office applications themselves that render the Infopath form. You don't need Infopath form services to be doing that.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like it won't work, because i wanned to try it if it will work for Windows SharePoint Services v3. Thought maybe adding some info programmatically would do the job, but looks like it wont.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here's a video on [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/In+the+Office/Creating-Custom-Document-Information-Panels/).